# Is there any way to observe the open action of the new window of all applications on SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I want to make a new macos Dock application ,it need to observe the new window (not application lunch ) opened events.

for now , I use the code below to get the running applications :

`let activeApps = workspace.runningApplications.filter({ $0.activationPolicy == .regular })`

and get the windows of the applications:

```
let appRef = AXUIElementCreateApplication(item.processIdentifier)

var value : AnyObject?
let axError:AXError = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(appRef, kAXWindowsAttribute as CFString, &value)
```

But I want to know , When will the new window be open or close ?  Is there any way to observe those events?

[image]

Just like chrome ,i want to do something when the second window(tab) active .

Think you ! Can someone offer some ideas?

But I want to know , When will the new window be open or close ?  Is there any way to observe those events?

Comment: Have you found a solution? *I want to make a new macos Dock application*. Me too! Maybe we can collaborate? If you are interested you can mail me on the mail I provided on my github profile page (you see it as a logged in github user). Sorry for not being "helpful" here. If I figure out a solution I'll come back to this post.